Event Creation page- Date fields interfering with Calendar selection drop down
My Google Calendar create event page is having display issues, which is preventing me from using it properly to create new events. Date fields are being overlaid on top of the calendar select drop down.
When I create a new event and try to select the calendar to apply it to, The date fields are being overlaid on top of the calendar select drop down menu, and it interferes with my ability to select the calendars that are at the top of the list, under the date fields. I've reinstalled, restarted, removed cookies etc and nothing has addressed this issue thus far.
Screenshot of the overlay issue
